# Unable to set minHour to 00 in flatpicker for maxDate

Tags: flatpickr

I am unable to set minHour for the maxDate to 00 hours.

```
  //calendar
  var calendar = $("#basicDate").flatpickr({
    dateFormat: "Y-m-d H:i",
    defaultDate: new Date(),
    enableTime: true,    
    time_24hr: true,
    minDate: new Date(),
    maxDate: new Date(),    
    minDateHasTime: true,
    maxDateHasTime: true,       
    hourIncrement: 1
  });

  var minDateRec = "2020-12-07T00:00";
  var maxDateRec = "2020-12-15T00:00";
  var minDateRecFom = new Date(minDateRec); 
  var maxDateRecFom = new Date(maxDateRec);

  calendar.set("minDate", minDateRecFom);
  calendar.set("maxDate", maxDateRecFom);
```

If I change maxDateRec to 2020-12-15T01:00 it works(as in the increment does not happen beyond 01 hours, but not for 00 hours - increment happens.

Codepen link below

https://codepen.io/DPK_RAO/pen/qBajMxg

Answer (score 0):

I changed the minute settings to 01, it works
var maxDateRec = "2020-12-15T00:01";